# carousel con swiper , react y react-id-swiper

Tags: reactjs

Estoy haciendo un carrusel del tipo Thumbs gallery con swiperjs y react-id-swiper 2.4.0, tengo el loop de los thump en false para que no se repitan las imágenes y tengo el  slideToClickedSlide: true, por lo que se supone que al hacer click en alguna imagen del thump pues mostraría la imagen en el slide superior, sin embargo esto no sucede, no se cual es el problema estoy usando swiper 5.2.0 (no puedo cambiar de versión)

Gracias por la ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { LightgalleryProvider, LightgalleryItem } from "react-lightgallery";
    import Swiper from "react-id-swiper";
    
    const ProductImageGallery = ({ product }) => {
    
      const [gallerySwiper, getGallerySwiper] = useState(null);
      const [thumbnailSwiper, getThumbnailSwiper] = useState(null);
    
      // effect for swiper slider synchronize
      useEffect(() => {
        if (
          gallerySwiper !== null &&
          gallerySwiper.controller &&
          thumbnailSwiper !== null &&
          thumbnailSwiper.controller
        ) {
          gallerySwiper.controller.control = thumbnailSwiper;
          thumbnailSwiper.controller.control = gallerySwiper;
        }
      }, [gallerySwiper, thumbnailSwiper]);
    
      // swiper slider settings
      const gallerySwiperParams = {
        getSwiper: getGallerySwiper,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        loopedSlides: 4,
        loop: true,
        effect: "fade"
      };
    
      const thumbnailSwiperParams = {
        getSwiper: getThumbnailSwiper,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        centeredSlides: false,
        loop: false,
        slidesPerView: 4,
        loopedSlides: 4,
        touchRatio: 0.2,
        freeMode: true,
     
        slideToClickedSlide: true,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
        },
        renderPrevButton: () => (
          <button className="swiper-button-prev ht-swiper-button-nav">
            <i className="pe-7s-angle-left" />
          </button>
        ),
        renderNextButton: () => (
          <button className="swiper-button-next ht-swiper-button-nav">
            <i className="pe-7s-angle-right" />
          </button>
        )
      };
    
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <div className="product-large-image-wrapper">
            {product?.discount || product?.new ? (
              <div className="product-img-badges">
                {product.discount ? (
                  <span className="pink">-{product.discount}%</span>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
                {product.new ? <span className="purple">New</span> : ""}
              </div>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
            <LightgalleryProvider>
              <Swiper {...gallerySwiperParams}>
                {product?.image &&
                  product.image.map((single, key) => {
                    return (
                      <div key={key}>
                        <LightgalleryItem
                          group="any"
                          src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + single}
                        >
                          <button>
                            <i className="pe-7s-expand1"></i>
                          </button>
                        </LightgalleryItem>
                        <div className="single-image">
                          <img
                            src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + single}
                            className="img-fluid"
                            alt=""
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
              </Swiper>
            </LightgalleryProvider>
          </div>
          <div className="product-small-image-wrapper mt-15">
            <Swiper {...thumbnailSwiperParams}>
              {product?.image &&
                product.image.map((single, key) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={key}>
                      <div className="single-image">
                        <img
                          src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + single}
                          className="img-fluid"
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
            </Swiper>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      );
    };
    
    ProductImageGallery.propTypes = {
      product: PropTypes.object
    };
    
    export default ProductImageGallery;


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVEuR.jpg
```